# How To Make Twitter Photo Card To Display In Image Original Size

Tags: twitter

How to display the image in the twitter card in original dimension?

For example I have this tweet using the Twitter Card (in Indonesian language)
https://twitter.com/urban_indo/status/367219691174903808

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XfYK.png

The image displayed is much smaller than the original image.

But then I upload the original image using twitter (http://pic.twitter.com), the image displayed is much larger and readable.
https://twitter.com/feliciadj/status/367185164603883522

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHSNI.png

Here's the meta in the HTML

```
<meta property="twitter:card" content="photo" />
<meta property="twitter:site" content="urban_indo" />
<meta property="twitter:title" content="ampera lt/lb 1000/1000 siap huni" />
<meta property="twitter:image:src" content="http://www.urbanindo.com/widget/property/539192592.jpg" />
<meta property="twitter:image:width" content="652" />
<meta property="twitter:image:height" content="480" />
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Summary card-For Normal image small size go directly for Summary cards.If you need bigger image go for Summary Large Image.